# Alterering the number of pages on a SSRS report output

Tags: reporting-services

When I need to select a specific report from a list of reports for some reason I get shown only half on one page and another half on page two. Is there a way that I can edit SSRS so pagination won't take place?

Thanks.

Comment: It's likely that the report data is being show on two pages because the report layout or margin and tablix aren't sized appropriately. Hard to tell without more information - can you post a screenshot of the paginated report? What is the export format? PDF?

Comment: I will see what I can do as I have to be a wee bit careful to what I post

Comment: You can also post a screenshot of the report in design view (like [this](http://i.technet.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC390759.gif) with ruler displayed), in addition to the report layout (landscape/portrait) and margin sizes. Just need to see if the tablix sizing is larger than layout/margin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing in the 
Report `properties-->InteractiveSize-->Height`

The height value sets the number of rows you are able to show in the report.

ex 5.5 will show 20 rows.